# Node.js is not giving any response and keep loading

Tags: node.js, mongoose

If I am using this function I am getting proper response.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   var products = Product.find();
   res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Shopping-Cart', products: products });
});
```

If I am using below function my local server is not giving any response and keep loading.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Product.find(function (err, docs){
    res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Shopping-Cart', products: docs });
  });  
});
```

Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: If you know that the first one works, why don't you use that?

Comment: kindly add match query in find method. You haven't provided a match query to find.

Comment: What's the template system you're using?

Comment: What's the helper library you're using for database? Is it Mongoose? or Sequelize?

Comment: I am using mongoose

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Add match object to find method.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Product.find({}, function (err, docs){
    res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Shopping-Cart', products: docs });
  });  
});
```

Comment: Can you explain from which library `.find` is?

Comment: Not working . I am using hbs- npm javascript handle bar

Comment: But why send this whole thing as parameter to find? `{}, function (err, docs){
    res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Shopping-Cart', products: docs });
  });` it doesn't make any sense

Comment: I thought he was using find of mongoose so that's why 2nd param is a callback here

Answer (score 0):

The second one is simply wrong. This whole thing :

```
function (err, docs){
    res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Shopping-Cart', products: docs });
  }
```

is being passed to the `find()` method as a parameter.It makes absolutely no sense

Correct would be this:

```
Product.find().then(docs=>{
 res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Shopping-Cart', products: docs })
}).catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

Comment: Can you explain from which library `.find` is?

Comment: @FelixKling could be Mongoose, could be Sequelize. You're right. That's missing info

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't specified the database you are using, I'll assume something similar to MongoDB. The first parameter to the find operation must be a query object if any.
[Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)

So, you can tweak your code in any of the ways like this:

1. `var products = await Product.find();   // Using async-await
    res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Shopping-Cart', products: products });`
2. `Product.find({}, function(err, products) {  // Using callbacks
     res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Shopping-Card', products: products });
    }`
3. `Product.find().then(function(products) {  // Using Promises
     res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Shopping-Card', products: products });
    }`